# Reading config sections using Custom config classes in C# and converting them to a list

Tags: c#, list, class, config

I have this in my `app.config` file:

```
<Configuration>
 <configsections>
  <section name="FeaturesSection" type="SampleCatalog.FeaturesSection" />
 </configsections>
 <FeaturesSection>
   <Feature Name="CCH" US="true" EM="false" Sequence="1" />
   <Feature Name="PLT" US="true" EM="false" Sequence="1" />
   <Feature Name="PD" US="true" EM="false" Sequence="1" />
 </FeaturesSection>
<Configuration>
```

My code in the class goes as below:

```
public class FeaturesSection:ConfigurationSection
{
 public FeatureCollection Features
 {
    get{return (FeatureCollection)base["Features"};
 }
}

public class FeatureCollection:ConfigurationElementCollection
{
   public Feature this[int index]{
     get{ return (Feature)BaseGet(index);}
     set{
        if(BaseGet(index)!= null)
          BaseRemoveAt(index);
        BaseAdd(index,value);
        }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
      return new Feature();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement          element){
      return ((Feature)element);
    }
}

public class Feature: ConfigurationElement
{
   [ConfigurationProperty("Name",IsRequired=true)]
   public string Name {get; set;}

   [ConfigurationProperty("US",IsRequired=true)]
   public bool US {get; set;}

   [ConfigurationProperty("EM",IsRequired=true)]
   public bool EM {get; set;}

   [ConfigurationProperty("Sequence",IsRequired=true)]
   public string Sequence {get; set;}
  }
```

Now when I run this code:

```
var mysection = (FeaturesSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("FeaturesSection");
```

I'm getting exceptions.

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for FeaturesSection: Could not load type 'SampleCatalog.FeaturesSection' from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. (C:\Users\Venkata_Poruri_Pavan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SampleCatalog\SampleCatalog\bin\Debug\SampleCatalog.vshost.exe.Con‌​fig line 4)

Please help, kindly accept my apologies as I couldn't paste the code here.

Thanks

Comment: ***WHAT*** exceptions do you get? Please post the full and exact error message(s) you get!

Comment: Couldn't load type SampleCatalog.FeaturesSection

Comment: Am I missing out on anything?

Comment: Do you have namespace `SampleCatalog.FeaturesSection`?

Comment: SampleCatalog is the namespace and the FeaturesSection is the class within the namespace.

Comment: Full Message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for FeaturesSection: Could not load type 'SampleCatalog.FeaturesSection' from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. (C:\Users\Venkata_Poruri_Pavan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SampleCatalog\SampleCatalog\bin\Debug\SampleCatalog.vshost.exe.Config line 4)

Comment: And there is nothing in front of `SampleCatalog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a config section type in your own assembly, you need to define that assembly in the `<configSection>` - try using this:

```
<configsections>
   <section name="FeaturesSection" 
            type="SampleCatalog.FeaturesSection, SampleCatalog" />
</configsections>
```

You need to specify the `type=` as fully-qualified class name, and then after a comma, define the **assembly** where that type is stored in. If you omit it (as you did in your post), .NET will check in the `System.Configuration` assembly - but of course, it won't find your custom class there!

**Update:** OK your code and config need a few little tweaks:

On the `FeaturesSection`, you need to add a `ConfigurationProperty` attribute to define under what name that collection of entries will be stored - something like this:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("Features")]
public class FeaturesSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    public FeatureCollection Features
    {
        get{return (FeatureCollection)base["Features"};
    }
}
```

On your `FeatureCollection` class, you need to define (with an attribute) what **type* of elements that collection will contain, and what to call the individual elements inside the collection:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(Feature), AddItemName = "Feature")]
public class FeatureCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public Feature this[int index]
    {
        get { return (Feature)BaseGet(index); }
        set 
        {
            if(BaseGet(index) !=  null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }

            BaseAdd(index,value);
        }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new Feature();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((Feature)element);
    }
}
```

And then your config needs to look like this:

```
<Configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- add the ASSEMBLY after the fully-qualified class name -->
        <section name="FeaturesSection" 
                 type="SampleCatalog.FeaturesSection, SampleCatalog" />
    </configSections>
    <FeaturesSection>
        <!-- this is the name defined on the FeaturesSection -->         
        <Features>
            <Feature Name="CCH" US="true" EM="false" Sequence="1" />
            <Feature Name="PLT" US="true" EM="false" Sequence="1" />
            <Feature Name="PD" US="true" EM="false" Sequence="1" />
        </Features>              
    </FeaturesSection>
<Configuration>
```

With this setup, you should be able to properly read out your custom config section.

Comment: ConfigurationErrorException: Unrecognized Element 'Feature'

Comment: @user3581188: updated my response with some code changes and a change in structure of the config section; I tested this on .NET 4.5 and it works for me

Comment: Error 18 Attribute 'ConfigurationProperty' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations.

Comment: @user3581188: where did you add the `ConfgurationProperty` attribute? My code as posted works (I testet it "live")

Comment: [ConfigurationProperty("Features")]
    public class FeaturesSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        public FeatureCollection Features
        {
            get { return (FeatureCollection) base["Features"]; } 
        }
    }

Comment: Now, I've tried by adding the ConfigurationProperty attribute to the public FeatureCollection Features property of the FeaturesSection class. But data from the section is still not being bound

Comment: @user3581188: uploaded my code and test project to http://1drv.ms/1SBXXOG - go and get it - for me, this **works** ....

Comment: Thank you very much marc, for your co-operation. Yup, Got it, I added the Configuration Property attribute to Features property in FeatureSection. And, made some type casting in the get set properties in the Feature class that inherits the ConfigurationElement. Below is the sample code for the each property in Feature Class. [ConfigurationProperty("Name", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string) this["Name"]; }
            set { this["Name"] = value; }
        }